# How do I convert a TTA file and its CUE sheet into several FLAC files?

Tags: conversion, split, flac

I have a sound file encoded in TTA format and a CUE sheet with its metadata. Which tools and commands do I need to convert it and split it into several FLAC files?

I tried using ffmpeg to convert the TTA file into a FLAC but it shows a "CRC error" and the resulting file has the wrong duration.

The TTA file itself plays fine in VLC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have `shntool` and `cuetools` installed.

Also install the tta encoder and decoder from  http://www.etree.org/shnutils/shntool/.

It needs to be compiled it with `g++` and `yasm`. Same goes for .ape files, which are also often used instead of .tta.

split **and name** .flac files:

`find . -name "*.cue" -execdir sh -c 'shnsplit -f "$1" -o flac -t "%n_%p-%t" "${1%.cue}.tta"' _ {} \;`

%n - track number
%p - performer
%t - track name

is taken from the .cue file for the .flac file names.

tag resulting, splitted .flac files:

`find . -name "*.cue" -execdir sh -c 'cuetag "$1" *.flac' _ {} \;`

Remove remaining .tta files. A simple `find . -name "*.tta" -delete` is sufficient.

For `shnsplit` to work, all necessary encoders / decoders need to be installed so it can read and write files. Modules for tta (and for the ape format) would need to be compiled from source, the others by installing the package (i.e. `flac`).

This works for all standard cases where .cue and .tta/.flac/.ape files have the same name, except for the extension.